# Why the screen is blank when i run my phonegap build google map app in an android phone?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

This is my first app that I built with Phonegap, the online one. I can run the map in my computer, but it shows blank on my phone. I have used several plugins before but all error.

is it the problem of my config file?

What should be included in this file if I want to run the map?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<widget xmlns   = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap   = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id          = "com.abc.def"
        versionCode = "10" 
        version     = "1.0.0" >

    <name>FYP</name>

    <description>
        Test only.
    </description>  

    <preference name="orientation" value="portrait"/>
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="true"/>
    <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto"/>
    <preference name="android-build-tool" value="gradle" /> 
    <preference name="API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID" value="KEY"/>


    <author email="name@email.com">
        name
    </author>

    <icon src="logo.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
    <icon src="logo.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" />
    <icon src="logo.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" />
    <icon src="logo.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" />
    <icon src="logo.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xxhdpi" />

    <gap:splash src="logo.png" gap:platform="android"/>


    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-googlemaps" source="npm">
        <param name="API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID" value="KEY" />
    </plugin>
</widget>
```

Comment: Please **answer the following questions in your post**. Since this appears to be your first post on this subject. Is this your first hybrid App?
Are you using the *Phonegap Desktop App*? Are you using [CLI, SDK or Build](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#001) ? Please do not assume the answer, please read the link. Once you have answer the question *in the post*, respond in the comments so I know you have added information to the post.

Comment: thx, now i try to use phonegap CLI.